# APA102 (HD107S) LED strip noise problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, noise, spi, motor-controller, apa102

I built POV display with HD107S LED strip (similar to APA102), It uses Raspberry Pi 3 and ESC module to drive the motor. At first on the breadboard the POV works well, at this time the strip LED circuit and the ESC circuit were separate.

But now after I made one PCB that contain the LED strip circuit and ESC, some noise appear at some LEDs while the POV displaying.
I found that the source of the noise is the motor, because when I shut it down the noise disappear.
**How can I eliminate this noise?**

This is before assembling:

[image]

And this after assembling in one PCB:
[image]

**NOTE: the noise doesn't appear in this photo, because it comes and go, it happen for some LEDs. For example when it suppose to display juste green or blue it display red or other color randomly.**

This the electronic schematic:[image]
Top copper: [image]
Bottom copper: [image]
Traces that pass high current:
[image]

Comment: Seems like your pcb design is faulty. You would need to fix this. Since we have no idea of your schematic or pcb layout we cannot offer any solid solutions.

Comment: @Kartman Now you have every thing . so can you tell me what is the problem and how to  fix it ?

Comment: Everything? Draw lines where the heavy currents are flowing on your pcb.

Comment: I just post image that shows  traces that pass high current

Comment: There is no decoupling capacitor on IC2 and its unused inputs are floating.

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors? Where is the motor connected? Does it have bypass capacitor and flyback diode?

Comment: @bobflux Do mean that if I add  decoupling capacitor  and connect unused inputs  to GND . This will solve the problem

Comment: It will solve one problem, but no-one can say if it will solve "the" problem...

Comment: @winny  C3_C4_C5  , Motor connected at X3, yes it has flyback diode and also bypass capacitor  (if you mean 100 nF between motor terminal)

Comment: Do you use PWM on the motor or just on/off?

Comment: I can't tell from the schematic. Where is decoupling for IC1, IC2 and IC3? How much does your 5 V drop to at the instant of motor turn-on? Again, I suspect insufficient decoupling. Also, please avoid slicing up your ground plane - no long traces there.